# Prove that second partial derivatives does not depend on the order of differentiation

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I'm trying to prove that if

$$\dfrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x \partial y} \quad \text{and} \quad  \dfrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y \partial x}$$

are continuous in an open set containing $a \in \mathbb{R}^2$, then they are equal using the definition of derivative:

First, I say

$$ \dfrac{\partial^2f}{\partial x \partial y} = \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x} \left( \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y} \right) = \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x} \left( \lim_{h \to 0} \dfrac{f(x,y+h)-f(x,y)}{h} \right) = \lim_{k \to 0} \dfrac{1}{k} \left( \lim_{h \to 0} \dfrac{f(x+k,y+h)-f(x+k,y)}{h} - \lim_{h \to 0} \dfrac{f(x,y+h)-f(x,y)}{h} \right) = \\ \lim_{k \to 0} \left( \lim_{h \to 0} \dfrac{f(x+k,y+h)-f(x+k,y)-f(x,y+h)+f(x,y)}{kh} \right) $$

Then I do the same thing for $ \dfrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y \partial x} $, and I get

$$ \lim_{h \to 0} \left( \lim_{k \to 0} \dfrac{f(x+k,y+h)-f(x+k,y)-f(x,y+h)+f(x,y)}{kh} \right)$$

My question is: am I allow to say that those limits are equal because both

$$\dfrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x \partial y} \quad \text{and} \quad  \dfrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y \partial x}$$ 
are continuous on $a$, or do I need something extra?
Please let me know if the question is clear enough, or if I made some silly mistakes :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is known as *Clairaut's Theorem*. Googling "proof of Clairaut's Theorem" yields many results including this one: http://www.math.ubc.ca/~feldman/m105/mixedPartials.pdf

Comment: For weaker result from the link there is [this pdf](http://cupid.economics.uq.edu.au/mclennan/Classes/Ec5113/ec5113-lec08-2.2.99.pdf)

Comment: FYI, the act of taking a derivative is called "differentiation," not "derivation."

Comment: @SantiMontouliu Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under these hypotheses the standard way to prove that is to consider some new auxiliary functions and use MVT theorem (refer to [Schwarz's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry_of_second_derivatives#Schwarz's_theorem)).

The same result can be proved also under the hypotheses of the existence of $f_x(x,y)$ and $f_y(x,y)$ in the open domain and that $f_x(x,y)$ and $f_y(x,y)$ are differentiable at the point $a$.